# Spyder does not launch even after proper installation

Tags: python, spyder, miniconda

## I'm trying to launch Spyder in a Python 3.6 virtual environment in Miniconda on Windows. The installation fails with conda, but it works with pip. However, when I try launching it through Anaconda Prompt, nothing happens.

```
(py36) C:\Users\User>conda update spyder3

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\envs\py36
  package name: spyder3
```

### If I try updating Spyder, then it gives an error saying that the package was not found.

```
(py36) C:\Users\User>conda install spyder
Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

 An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

I keep getting the above error. I have tried all answers to this query, but none of them work for me.

Comment: related?  https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064